# Google Analytics: tracking traffic from multiple devices

Tags: android, iphone, google-analytics, mobile-website, google-analytics-api

I'm working on a mobile website that we plan to implement within a android and iphone app as a web view.

I would like to know if is possible to track the source of each pageview. For example which pageviews come from the iphone app, android app or regular browser. Also would like to know if this is possible using just one google analytics account.

For reporting we would like to have it like this:

- http://domain.com/index.php - 200 views

  - AndroidApp - 50 views
  - IphoneApp - 100 views
  - Browser - 50 views

is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is already tracked for you under

```
audience -> moble -> overview -> Device Category - gives you either mobile or desktop.
audience -> moble -> devices -> mobile device info - will give you what type of mobile it was.
audience -> technology -> browser & OS - will give you the browser as well.
```

Edit: To respond to coment below that you cant see pageviews in the Mobile device info screen. You can create your own dashboard widget to show this information.

[image: Click add widget]

Click add widget to open the next window

[image]

add Mobile device info as your dimension and now you can add pageviews as your metric. Click ok when you are done.

[image]

Comment: "audience -> moble -> devices" doesnt let me track pageviews tracks. Also i want to know if the page was viewed from a browser , or from within a Iphone Application or Android Application. 

I'm now experimenting creating a google analytic custom dimension to see if that works... Will let know.

Comment: Sorry about the wait.  I added some info for you on how to create your own custom widget to show mobile device info and pageviews.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

- Set the useragent in the webview. Once a user agent is set, GA will infer the platform etc for the hits.
- You could also set some custom dimensions that indicates the platform the webview is running on.

  - Once you do that, you will be able to segment your reports by your dimension and see which platform is getting what traffic.